# NextJS seemingly ignored my homepage when I build, (and mysteriously, one other page). It's "remembering" it's very first iteration?

Tags: javascript, nginx, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, static-html

In local development, everything is fine.

In production, my homepage "remembers" its prehistoric "first version"! along with one other page! I don't even know how it's getting information on how to look like. It's old CSS. old layout. old content. It's like a wayback machine!

It's like NextJS just decided to never update my homepage (and one other page) in production for whatever reason.

[My buggy homepage](https://teambrg.com/diablo-4)

[Other buggy page](https://teambrg.com/diablo-4/classes-general/d4-general-leveling-guide-all-classes)

Normal pages look like: [normal page](https://teambrg.com/diablo-4/db/aspects)

So weird... Is there some kind of setting I might have toggled that prevents these from building? Next build shows success on these, though?

- Clearing browser data NOT WORKING. (Dev mode reloads, manual, everything)
- Incognito, other browsers, NOT WORKING.
- Asked a friend(s) to visit, NOT WORKING. (so its not MY local cache at least...)

  Stack is NGINX NEXTJS. Again, to clarify in my local machine everything is A-OK!

I'm at a complete loss, because the production server (even my local machine) wouldn't know how to build the page to those buggy specifications! Could it really be a cache thing?

Comment: What's your deployment process?

Comment: Im pretty much a novice when it comes to "deployment" haha, so it's pretty primitive all things considered. I manually "next build" locally, then git push to my VPS. run next build on production VPS (is this even necessary?), then use pm2 to next start. All "self-hosted".

I just honestly cannot for the life of me understand how those "buggy pages" are even getting this information on how to construct themselves. The "legacy" portion of my site has a wordpress / cloudflare pairing... but I purged that too...

Comment: Delete the .next folder on the server then, run the build command

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried this already, and it didn't work. Tried it again just now for "fun", and the result is the same. Didnt work at all.